# Как скрыть EditText когда теряется фокус?

Tags: android

У меня в Activity имеется скрытый EditText.
При нажатии на кнопку, он появляется.
 1. Как сделать, чтобы при появлении вылазила сразу клавиатура?
 2. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии куда угодно(кроме кнопки, по которой он появляется) он скрывался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `editTxt.requestFocus();`
2. [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) Для всех view устанавливаем этот обработчик, проверяем куда нажали и прячем если надо. Прятать аналогично показу.

Answer (score 1):

1) Вообще то если задан InputType то клава автоматом показывается и обычно наоборот часто проблема как ее скрыть. В любом случае попробуйте так

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputManager.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

2) Надо ловить [`Activity.onTouchEvent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) - только не путать с `View.onTouchEvent()`! И вызывать `EditText.setVisibility()`

Answer (score -1):

1. как скрыть клаву - был вопрос и вообще найти ответ несложно
2. что бы вылазила сразу - вызывай ее при нажатии кнопки
3. повешай листенер на всю активи и по нему прячь клаву